# Azure AD : "Authorization_RequestDenied" when attempting to update application programmatically

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to update an application using Microsoft graph API, programmatically.
Steps i performed as follows:

1. Get an Access token programmatically by providing the user assertion.
2. Execute "PATCH" request for updating the certificate.

Request URL:
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/<-application obj ID->

3. When i execute from graph explorer, request gets completed successfully.
4. I get following error when done programmatically:

   ```
    {"error": {
    "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
    "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2020-11-04T11:47:48",
      "request-id": "132aba35-6d34-4940-8806-935ce581bd53",
      "client-request-id": "132aba35-6d34-4940-8806-935ce581bd53"
    }}}
   ```

I have granted following Application permissions for the app as shown in screenshot:
[image]

Any other permissions needed to update an application? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing permission  `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy, Application.ReadWrite.All`.please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for more information

[image]

Comment: Right. Thanks Sruthi!